# Logging from Chrome console to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm looking for a way get a console output from Google Chrome into my python program. I have a script coded in JS that finishes in around 1 second, but my python implementation (exactly same logic, etc, the only diff is that it's in Python and not JS) takes about 15 seconds to run. Therefore I'm looking for a way to get the printout in Chrome console to my python program.

This is the current way I'm doing it:

Python program uses pyautogui to click and does what it needs to do inside to trigger the function running in JS.

JS completes the function in 1s and prints to console, something like:

`(22) [6, 4, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0]`

I need to get that into my python program so it can does the rest of the stuff..

Comment: Why though? If you just want to run a piece of JavaScript, you can use PyMiniRacer, or even shell out to Node.js. Why go through Chrome?

Comment: I need the execution time to be as fast as possible, so if I already have the Chrome tab open, and my Python program can automatically run the function via mouse clicks/keyboard presses, then it'll reduce the amount of time to get the result